# Rust Can't import Singleton From global space into another module in another file

Tags: module, rust, singleton

Using the `lazy_static` library to create a singleton. I am unable to access that singleton in a module in another file. If the module is defined below the main function I can access it fine.

Given a main file such as the following, `test_stuff` can access gamedata fine:

```
extern crate gamedata;
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;


lazy_static! {
    pub static ref GAMEDATA: &'static str = "I am a test STrings";
} 

fn main() {
    println!("Game Data:{}",*GAMEDATA);
    let obj = gamedata::readinginstatic::readinginstatic {
        structure:"working".to_string()
    };
    obj.print_static();
}

mod test_stuff {
    use ::GAMEDATA;
    fn printthing() {
        println!("herenow:{}", *GAMEDATA);
    }
}
```

With a `lib.rs` file such as:

```
pub mod readinginstatic;
```

And a module in another file `readinginstatic.rs` as described below:

```
use ::GAMEDATA;

pub struct readinginstatic {
    pub structure:String,
}

impl readinginstatic {
    pub fn print_static(&self) {
        println!("In Print static width:{}", *::GAMEDATA);
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> not found in the crate root

When trying to import `GAMEDATA`.

Is it possible to access a `lazy_static` singleton in another module if it is defined in another file?

To insure I have provided a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example here is my whole example code on GitHub: https://github.com/camccar/moduleError

Comment: Just a small hint for the future: try sticking to Rust's coding conventions. In particular, types are `UpperCamelCase` (e.g. `ReadingInStatic`) and modules and functions are `snake_case` (e.g. `reading_in_static` and `test_thing`). Using correct names also means that the compiler won't emit a bunch of warnings. Additionally, proper indentation and spacing also vastly increases readability. You should really use correct formatting in your code. If you're unsure, try `rustfmt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::GAMEDATA` refers to some value called `GAMEDATA` in the crate root of the `gamedata` crate. However where you defined `GAMEDATA` was not in that crate, it was in your `main.rs` file which has `gamedata` as a dependency.

So what you're trying to do here is reach out of a crate use something from the crate that is depending on you, which I'm not sure but I don't think is allowed.

You could consider inverting this and instead initialising GAMEDATA inside your `gamedata` crate instead and if you need to use it in main you can just `use` it normally:

```
extern crate gamedata;

use gamedata::GAMEDATA;

fn main(){
    println!("Game Data:{}", *GAMEDATA);

    ...
}
```

Alternatively if `GAMEDATA` is not something your game data crate should know how to define, you could construct it inside main and pass it to some function in the `gamedata` crate as a parameter.